# Dataflow - 20 streaming Windmill RPC errors for a stream

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, grpc, rpc, google-cloud-pubsub

I've been using dataflow and pubsub for streaming for over a year, and today without me changing anything dataflow is not reading from pubsub anymore. At first, I was getting the below error in my logging but it stopped popping up once I updated pubsub to the latest version and apache beam sdk from 2.10.0 to 2.17.0

20 streaming Windmill RPC errors for a stream, last was: org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p13p1.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: NOT_FOUND: Requested entity was not found.

I see the below link but at the end it just says GCP is working on it and does not say if the writer did anything to fix the issue. How does this get fixed and want is causing it?

[Dataflow: streaming Windmill RPC errors for a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58693680/dataflow-streaming-windmill-rpc-errors-for-a-stream)

Comment: This sounds like a production pipeline issue. In that case, I'd advise you to file a support ticket to Dataflow support. Furthermore, something that comes to mind is whether your bucket could have a cleanup policy for files that had some files deleted and your pipeline is missing them?

Comment: I filed a case with them because afterward the jobs wouldn't cancel.They can force cancel them on their end so I'm waiting to hear back. Thanks, Pablo.